# Python software development (CSV to Pandas to SQL or CSV to SQL to Pandas)

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have multiple csv files that I want to manipulate(calculate mean, sum, etc.) and after that I want to store them in a SQLite database.

But I want to know what is the most proper way to do that.

CSV to SQL and manipulate with Pandas

OR

CSV, manipulate with Pandas and store in SQL

For example, I want to store all the data in this table http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=GOOG&region=USA&culture=en-US.
I will update yearly and add 2013,2014,etc. In my SQL table.
I'll create a column where I will have 10 year average for each rows, etc.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, pandas's support for manipulating CSV files is far beyond that of its ability to manipulate SQL databases, though there is a significant effort right now to improve the latter by leaps and bounds!

Take a look at [the `read_csv` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files). This is one of the most flexible, fast, and generally powerful text file readers/writers out there for data analysis applications.

On the other hand [`read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries) can only write to `sqlite` databases and doesn't store the `index`.

With `read_csv` you can even read [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex) objects (hierarchical indexes)!

If you aren't tied to a database, then I would recommend that you look into using pandas [`HDF5`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables) for persistence. I use this all the time and it works great.

In summary, I would recommend the first choice you listed if you *must* use a database since writing anything to database is not going to work unless you're using `sqlite`, but you can *read* from others besides `sqlite`.

Comment: I'll look at HDf5 seems interesting ! Thanks

Comment: I think also MySQL works with sql (and according to a couple of people postgres, though looking at codebase don't see how).